# OpsWorks' Static Webserver & CORS

Tags: cors, aws-opsworks

Is there an easy way to enable CORS on an OpsWorks Static Webserver?

I know I could use S3 instead but OpsWorks is easier to deploy from (Git integration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opsworks static webserver is based on Nginx. Heres an example of [enabling cors in nginx](http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html) . As for actually getting this done in opsworks, you could ssh into each instance and do it manually or look at creating your own cookbook based on the [opsworks nginx cookbook](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/nginx/recipes/default.rb).

Answer (score -1):

Can you use Node.js appserver instead of Static Webserver? Then you could do  "npm install cors"